# how to get data from dataset

Tags: c#, datatable

my Gridview always get null datatable ,error message:`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`, but i donot know which code is missing. 
Thanks for help!!!

**.CS**

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("abc");
        dt = getDT(formatDate); //string[] formatDate ={2013-01-01,2013-05-01..}
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["abc"].DefaultView; 
         //if change to dt , it works ==> GridView2.DataSource =dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }

}

private DataTable getDT(string[] date)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("RowID", typeof(Int16));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    for (int i = 0; i < date.Length; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, date[i]);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: what are the values of formatDate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the code -

```
Protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("abc");
        dt = getDT(formatDate);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["abc"].DefaultView;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }

}

private DataTable getDT(string[] date)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("RowID", typeof(Int16));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    for (int i = 0; i < date.Length; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, date[i]);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

**Inside the `getDT` function you are again creating a new `DataTable` which does not have a name. You should either send the table as reference or create it inside the function**. Either of the following solution will work -

```
Protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("abc");
        dt = getDT(dt, formatDate);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["abc"].DefaultView;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }

}

private DataTable getDT(DataTable dt, string[] date)
{
    //DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("RowID", typeof(Int16));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    for (int i = 0; i < date.Length; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, date[i]);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

OR,

```
Protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = getDT(formatDate);
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables["abc"].DefaultView;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }

}

private DataTable getDT(string[] date)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("abc");

    dt.Columns.Add("RowID", typeof(Int16));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    for (int i = 0; i < date.Length; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, date[i]);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

EDIT: Only for HassanNisar
@HassanNisar .. this is the debugger output -

[image]

Comment: can we assign string value to `DateTime` column of `DataTable`?

Comment: @HassanNisar not sure what you meant?.

Comment: `dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));` type is `DateTime` then can we do this `dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, date[i]);`?

Comment: @HassanNisar Yes you can. It will be converted to datetime, but you have to have it in proper formatted string - I have added a screenshot for you.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for explanation :). My upvote for you.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass name of DataTable you are creating. By default `DataTable` does not have name, that's why you can't get it by name `abc`.

```
private DataTable getDT(string name, string[] date)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(name);

    dt.Columns.Add("RowID", typeof(Int16));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    for (int i = 0; i < date.Length; i++)    
        dt.Rows.Add(i + 1, date[i]);        

    return dt;
}
```

Then creating table will look like:

```
ds.Tables.Add(getDT("abc", formatDate));
```

Also you can add null-check for date parameter.

---

NOTE: I suggest you to improve naming of your code. See [C# Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). And you don't need to use DataSet here - simply bind to DataTable:

```
private DataTable CreateDatesTable(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Dates");

    dt.Columns.Add("RowID", typeof(Int16));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    foreach(var date in dates)        
       dt.Rows.Add(dt.Rows.Count + 1, date); 

    return dt;
}
```

Usage:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dates = formattedDates.Select(DateTime.Parse);
    GridView2.DataSource = CreateDatesTable(dates);
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: sorry, can you indicate what should i change